# wait for php script then download

Tags: java, android

i have a php script which creates a file if it not exists. the php script sends the file after it created it. now i have the problem that my download class can't download it (i don't know exactly why) when the php file is creating a new file. but if the php script sends a cached file the download works.
Is there any way to let the android wait until the php script is done executing?

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Directory;
import android.util.Log;

public class DownloadMP3 extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    private OnTaskRunning listener;
    public DownloadMP3(OnTaskRunning listener){
        this.listener=listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        int count;
        try {
            Log.d("Info", "create file");
            Download down = new Download();
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(down.JSON(conf.d + "convert.php?v=" + url[0]));
            Log.d("Info","json file: " + jObject.get("fle"));

            URL u = new URL(conf.d + "convert.php?v=" + jObject.get("fle"));
            Log.d("Info", "dl u");
            URLConnection conexion = u.openConnection();
            Log.d("Info", "dl op");
            conexion.connect();
            Log.d("Info", "dl co");
            File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Music/VBT Splash/");
            Log.d("Info", "dl di");
            if (!directory.exists() || !directory.isDirectory()){
                directory.mkdirs();
            }



            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(u.openStream());

            String filename = conexion.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");

            String file = filename.substring(filename.indexOf("\"")+1, filename.lastIndexOf("\""));

            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Music/VBT Splash/" + file);

            int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
            byte data[] = new byte[4096];

            long total = 0;

            listener.onTaskStarted();
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                output.write(data, 0, count);
                publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / lenghtOfFile));
            }
            Log.d("Info", "dl done");
            listener.onTaskDone();
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        listener.onTaskProgress(progress[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(int result) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must convey a re-direct to your client code. If you just hit the full file path url , and it doesn't exists, it won't be downloaded. So instead, first get download url from script. ( a new one will be created if it doesn't exists) then, download that url. That makes a total of 2 requests to server.

Comment: Same problem, but different solution: always send the file through the PHP script, using `readfile`.

Comment: Currently i am sending the file using readfile. What you mean is first execute the php file and just give the url to the file and then download the real file?

Comment: @Styler2go yes, In first request you get a string from php script, make second request using that string url.

Comment: I have edited the code above. But it is not working.  first of all, i now create a `Download` Object and let it download the response from the server. Any Idea why it is not working? it just stops after the `create file` and there are no error messages in LogCat